# How to make a 3-year-old eat?

Tags: toddler, eating

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get my toddler to eat as well for us as he does at daycare?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/5806/how-can-i-get-my-toddler-to-eat-as-well-for-us-as-he-does-at-daycare)

We have tried to feed her but when she is really hungry she only drinks milk and goes to sleep. We have waited for a while to wait for her hunger to rise, but that does not happen. We have waited for a few hours and she would only eat a few salad pieces and then run away, so waiting is ruled out.

I have tried to compose a poem and sing to my child and she did take food. Diversion and competition has worked so far like

> Eat or else your sister will eat your meal etc.,

How have you attempted to make a child eat?

Comment: Maybe you should add some detail to the question.  Are you trying to say that feeding your daughter is difficult, and if so, in what ways?  In general I'd avoid coddling any child to get her to eat. In almost all cases, when a child is truly hungry, she will eat, and will be better off for doing so naturally and not requiring songs or other enticements.

Comment: We have waited for few hours and she would only eat few salad pieces and then run away, so waiting is ruled out.

Comment: That's kids for you.. they are like birds sometimes. Picking here and there. Just have to be patient.

Answer (score 2):

I would simply wait for her to get hungry.  Three hours is not so long for a child to wait to eat at that age; three year olds sometimes eat like sparrows in my experience, boys and girls alike.  Though it may cause you some anxiety, try simply waiting one day for her to get hungry, instead of giving in after three hours; I can almost guarantee she will eat.

Only very rarely is a child's appestat (hunger regulation mechanism) truly broken, and if your child is one of those ultra-rare cases, she still won't perish from this simple experiment.  Good luck.