# My Fussy 14 month old REFUSES to eat any type of food at home EXCEPT her baby bottle!

Tags: toddler, food, eating

My daughter is 14 months old and her appetite has not been any better since she turned almost 11 months old i want to say. Its been an on going struggle at home. She will drink her bottle more often than she will eat. In addition when she's with her babysitter she will eat whatever the lady makes her (ex.: cheerios with milk, pieces of chicken, soup, rice, mashed potatoes etc.) I've tries giving her the same and she just won't eat…its a constant fight.

However if it's not a cracker or a couple cheerios for her to eat with her hands she will not eat. If she sees me eating a bag of chips she will ask for some - but I simply cannot give her something that does not benefit her health as a growing baby. And what she does eat isn't enough - at most it will be two or three bites of her food or mine. Other than that I am unable to get her to take anymore bites or mouthfuls.

Now she's 14 months and the struggle continues. Even if she sees me eat - she will look, smack her lips but when I offer her food she turns away. If I attempt to feed her she tightens her jaw shut and presses her lips closed. Or she'll press her lips and make a spitting sound to show me she refuses to eat.

I've tried different things from finger foods to changing her food to making the same food her babysitter feeds her. Moreover she has lost weight but still seems very energetic and playful as usual. At this point I have no clue what else to do?

Sorry but the solutions to a similar questions simply do not work for me. Therefore I need a BETTER solution. Thanks!

Comment: Is there some specific reason the other answers don't work?  If so, please add it to your question. As it stands now, your question is pretty much identical to the one I asked, with the exception of the age (which shouldn't impact the answers significantly; certainly what was suggested on my answer seems applicable in your situation given the info you've provided).  We'd love to see you get an answer that works, but if there are specific circumstances that make your situation distinct, we'll need to know what they are to give you appropriate answers.

Comment: Also... you say what she eats now isn't enough.  Is she losing weight? Gaining weight? Staying about the same?  Has your pediatrician commented on her growth (or lack of it)?  What have you tried aside from changing the foods you've offered her?

Comment: Yes because the situation IS NOT the same and her eating habits are completely different. Therefore my question ,though it may seem the same or similar, it is not.

Comment: If the situation is not the same, then you need to explain why it is different. Because what you posted here is: your daughter eats for the babysitter, but does not eat for you (although she'll drink from her bottle, and it sounds like she'll eat certain foods, like crackers and cheerios).  Which doesn't seem different at all.

Comment: I edited my question as you requested and yes my situation is different. Thanks!

Comment: I still don't understand how your situation is different. Not wanting her to eat chips doesn't really make the situation different. Her losing weight points to a difference in severity, but doesn't really show any difference in the *situation*. I've asked the other moderators here to take a look and see if there is something I'm missing, and other members of the community are welcome to chime in (and those with sufficient reputation can vote to reopen if they seem fit).  I have added the toddler tag back in, as it should be here since your daughter is 14 months of age.

Comment: Nymphea, while I see there are some differences in your situation to the duplicate, I **do not** see what I can see as **significant** differences that would impact my answer to the question.  Any suggestion I might make to you, I would also make for the older question.  More clarification really is needed about specifically what makes dealing with your situation different from a perspective of the person answering - what is different that would make the approach different?  Otherwise, I'll have to agree that it is a duplicate.

Comment: I have added an edit to my answer to Beofett's original question because of some updated information I have had since I originally wrote my answer there.  Please check [this out again](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/a/6743/2876) and see if the addition at the bottom is helpful to you at all.

Comment: Why is a 14 month old still on a bottle? That's the only question I have. If it's there, she's gonna take it. I would stop offering it, put her on a cup and let her feed herself as often as possible. She's 14 months old. Unless she has some sort of health issue, she should be able to do this. Also, how long is each new strategy tried? Changing things constantly can stress a kid out or even an adult for that matter. Also, stop eating things in front of her you don't want her to eat. Money see, monkey do. Eat what you want her to eat. That's what daycares do. We eat what the kids eat.